# `npm start` in docker ends with: Please install a supported C++11 compiler and reinstall the module

Tags: c++11, docker, npm, docker-compose

I got a issue while running a docket container, getting error:

```
error: uncaughtException: Compilation of µWebSockets has failed and there is no pre-compiled binary available for your system. Please install a supported C++11 compiler and reinstall the module 'uws'.
```

Here is a full stack trace: http://pastebin.com/qV0hzRxL

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.7-slim

# ----- I added this, but it didn't help
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc g++
RUN gcc --version
RUN g++ --version
# ------------------------------------

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV NODE_ENV docker

RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

- Then I build successfully it with: `sudo docker-compose build --no-cache chat-ws` (`chat-ws` is name of image)
- And `sudo docker-compose up chat-ws` ends with error.

Note: Docker image is part of composition in `docker-compose`.

---

**EDIT:** Parts of `docker-compose.yml`

```
chat-ws:
  build: ./dockerfiles/chat-ws
  links:
    - redis
    - chat-api
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
  volumes_from:
    - data_chat-ws
```

---

And:

```
data_chat-ws:
  image: node:6.7-slim
  volumes:
    - ${PATH_CHAT_WS}:/usr/src/app
  command: "true"
```

Any ideas? Please?
Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 1):

To me, the problem was my darwin version was 57 (OSX 10.12.6)

> npm install uws # to me was uws@8.14.1, thit has my darwin version

now copy the compiled version to your OS

> cp node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_57.node node_modules/socketcluster-server/node_modules/uws/

Answer (score 0):

It's late, and I only really learned about `docker-compose` and Stack Overflow just today, so forgive me if I am making some really obvious mistakes here, but:

- Have you tried running the image you made? `docker run yourimage`, including whichever command. Does that run fine?
- In your `docker-compose`, why does your `data_chat-ws` service have as an image `node:6.7-slim`? Shouldn't that be the image you built, i.e. `image: chat-ws`?

This is where I would start debugging: first make sure you are actually able to run the image, leaving aside all `docker-compose` stuff, and only when it runs fine, add it to your `docker-compose.yml`. To help checking whether you can actually run your container, check the example in their official documentation [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) (scroll down to the 'How to use this image' part of the page).

Comment: Thanks, I reallize there is missing parts of `docker-compose.yml` there, I have added it between lines an marked it as **EDIT**.